# Bash script if else

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement

I am writing my first bash script to loop through a CSV with old username to new usernames. I only read the new username to make the linux account

```
while read old_name new_name
do
   new_name="$(tr [A-Z] [a-z] <<< $new_name)"
   echo $new_name
   cmd= useradd -g groupid -s /bin/ksh $new_name >> $LOGFILE 2>&1
   echo password | passwd --stdin $new_name
```

But some users already exist and don't need a new password. Only the new users need the password.

When a user already exists I get `useradd: user 'username' already exists`

How can I fix this?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/28526/67817

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The linked question covers how to determine whether a user already exists but I would suggest making a couple of other modifications to your script:

```
# always use -r (raw) switch unless you have a specific reason not to
while read -r old_name new_name
do
    new_name=${new_name,,} # convert to lowercase using parameter expansion
    if ! id -u "$new_name" &>/dev/null # check user doesn't exist
    then
        useradd -g groupid -s /bin/ksh "$new_name" &>"$LOGFILE"
        passwd --stdin "$new_name" <<<password # avoid useless echo + pipe
    fi
done
```

As mentioned in the comments, you may have to resort to your original method to convert `$new_user` to lowercase if you're using an older version of bash (the `${var,,}` syntax is a bash 4 feature). If you use `[:upper:]` and `[:lower:]` instead of `[A-Z]` and `[a-z]` then your script will be less locale-specific, which may be something to be aware of.

Comment: Thanks Tom. i will test i tomorrow in my test env.

Comment: `${new_name,,}` requires `bash` 4, though. Earlier versions will have to use `new_name=$(tr [:upper:] [:lower:] <<< "$new_name")`.